# Can't change my store back after adding prepaid credit card

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-id

I went to Japan, changed my store to Japan and added a prepaid credit card to purchase apps. Now I am back in Dubai and I can't change the store to Dubai now. My WhatsApp is about to expire in 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

you probably have money left on your Apple account which you created in Japan. the other possibility is that you may have some subscriptions to which you subscribed in Japan (for example, Apple Music, any news papers and so on).

so you would have to spend all that money or unsubscribe to be able to change the store

Comment: If it is a prepaid credit card and not a gift card, it shouldn't matter if there is more money on it, since the account wouldn't know this.

Comment: How about deleting the apps downloaded from the Japanese app store, logging out and changing to the Dubai store and then downloading again from that store, is that a possibility?

Comment: @Anders, I meant he might have money left on his Apple account, not on prepaid card. if you have money left on your Apple account, Apple does not allow you to change stores

Answer (score 0):

How about deleting the apps downloaded from the Japanese app store, logging out and changing to the Dubai store and then downloading again from that store, is that a possibility?